# Remove from an array a specific character

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If my variable named test_var has this array:

```
[". test.1", ". test/2", ". test.3"]
```

how is it possible to take back this

```
["test.1", "test/2", "test.3"]
```

This is just an example I don't know how many keys/values my array could have because it is in dynamic code and if all of them have this `.` character which I want to remove. Is there any simple way to check my array and if it contains the previous character remove otherwise leave it as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** to do that

```js
var arr = [". test.1", ". test/2", ". test.3"];

arr = arr.map(function( v) {
  return v.match(/\b.*$/)[0];
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use lists comprehension:

```
a = [". test.1", ". test/2", ". test.3"]

a.map(function(x) { return x.substring(2)})
```

For more complex transformations, you may want to use regex